# Custom Exception that throws only specific Exceptions

Tags: java

I have a method which will throw SecurityException,NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException.

I want to Custom Exception clause so that it will throw only the above Exception.

If any other exception comes, my Custom Exception clause should not throw it.

Is there a way or two to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: ...Why?  Each of these exceptions have a distinct and clear meaning.  Why do you feel it'd be better to combine them into one?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can test the type of exception, for example:

```
if (e instanceof SecurityException) {
    // do sth;
} else if (e instanceof NoSuchFieldException) {
    // do sth;
} else if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
    // do sth;
}
```

Comment: You are asking me to add the instanceOf check in CustomException clause or in the clause which i will use CustomException?

Comment: If in CustomExcption clause, which method i should overide ?

Comment: Sorry, I am a Chinese, my English is so so and I don`t understand  exactly.